# Call function after view have load

Tags: ios

So i have this function that parses data from an url string and set labels.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self parseAndSetLabels];
}
```

The problen is that if you have a bad connection it can take a while and it look likes the app froze, but it actually do the parseAndSetLabels function before it animates the view.

So how can i make the viewLoad and after that run my function ?

(like in this order)

```
-(void)main
{
     [self viewDidLoad]
     [self parseAndSetLabels];
}
```

Comment: There's no difference between your two statements - they'll perform the same thing.  What you have to do is start a thread that calls parseAndSetLabels and then posts a message back when it's complete.

Comment: In your case you should only populate view in viewDidLoad with some initial data (maybe cached from last session) and start parseAndSetLabels which should be moved to another thread. This way GUI won't freeze. EDIT: sorry for almost duplicate comment, i guess it took me 8 minutes to type it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Nickolay O. said, use `NSURLConnection` asynchronously with its delegate methods or you can call `parseAndSetLabels` method in your `viewDidAppear:` method.
Placing your call inside this last method, it will be called every time the view appears but if you don't want this, you can use simple boolean conditions to call this method only once, like in this example:

```
YourController.h

@property (nonatomic) BOOL condition;

YourController.m

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.condition = YES;
}
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if (self.condition)
    {
        [self parseAndSetLabels];
        self.condition = NO;
    }
}
```

However, in your case, `NSURLConnection` and its delegate are the best solutions.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to be too specific without seeing the content of your `parseAndSetLabels`, but in general you should not be performing network operations synchronously in the `viewDidLoad` code. You should set the labels to temporary placeholders, and initiate an asynchronous call that takes a block that executes on completion of the asynchronous operation. You should be setting the real values of your labels from inside that asynchronous block.

Answer (score 0):

Use async NSURLConnection (or secondary thread) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can as well download and parse your data before even you initiating the view controller. So you just set the labels in your viewDidLoad method with the parsed data.
And you can as well initiate the viewcontroller once your app receives a signal in  connectionDidfinishLoading (if you are using Async mode).

If in case, the view controller you are talking about is the root viewcontroller then,
 are you using a synchronous call to web service or asynchronous call. but that input from you will help.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like a performance with a delay:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(something) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0f];
```

Comment: it'a hacky solution which may lead bigger problems in case the delay is not sufficient or too long than necessary. Bad practice.